# Is it safe to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php, urls, server, iis

I've looked at other answers and I see that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is usually recommended and is the accepted answer for getting the current page URI along with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

I looked at the WP source code and it's widely used there too.

But I found some controversy about it not working on IIS. Perhaps it was only an issue in the past? I even tried to install IIS in my PC to check it out but I can't configure it and it seems like an overkill just to confirm this.

It seems like it's the only SERVER variable that includes the information I want:

/pane-slug`/nggallery/tags/dark-colors/`

the highlighted example part is added via NextGEN Gallery 2 and is only accessible through the  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, nothing else. Previously it was accessible using get_query_var, not anymore.

If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is not set, faking it through setting it manually and creating it based on `PHP_SELF` and `QUERY_STRING` brings inequivalent results.

So is it safe to rely on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` being always available for use on WP installs? I assume it is since the WP core code uses it, but I had to ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will not be empty in WordPress, because it is filled in `wp_fix_server_vars()` (file `wp-includes/load.php`).

This function is called in `wp-settings.php` before any plugin is loaded. So you can use it.

But always escape the value. It is global and can be changed by any other code, so you cannot trust its value.

A different case is accessing the value per

```
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI');
```

The write access by WordPress will *not* affect the value, because `filter_input()` is always taking the original value. So while this is the more modern and clean approach, it might fail in some circumstances. See also [this thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232975/php-filter-inputinput-server-request-method-returns-null).

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent information. Now I can uninstall IIS and forget it :) I mass searched WP files for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but somehow skipped over what you have pointed out. Of course I'll escape it, I don't trust anything. Just needed to know if it is usable. Thanks again.